# Adding class as per LI postion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below markup,

```
<ul>
<li>1</li> //light BG
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li> //light BG
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
......
</ul>
```

I want to add class `dark` and `light`, as per position of `li`.

- First `li` should be `light`
- 2nd,3rd should be `dark`
- 4th, 5th should be `light`
- same pattern....

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use CSS3 selectors for this? Just curious.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('ul li:nth-child(3n-2)').addClass('light');

$('ul li::not(:nth-child(3n-2))').addClass('dark');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/185/)**

Comment: I just looked at the nth-child documentation. Wouldn't it be better to use eq()? " With :nth-child(n), all children are counted, regardless of what they are... With :eq(n) only the selector attached to the pseudo-class is counted"

Comment: @Thomas I'll go for `:nth-child`, better for your situation and easiest

Answer (score 1):

Play with the modulo operator, it's fun!

```
$( 'li' ).each( function() {
    // Cache some variables
    var el = $( this ),
        index = el.index();

    if ( index % 3 === 0 || index % 3 === 1 ) {
        el.addClass( 'light' );
    }
    else {
        el.addClass( 'dark' );
    }
} );
```

<sub>PS: thanks [Zeta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139697/zeta) for helping me with the modulo operations /o/</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Is this the pattern you are after:

http://jsfiddle.net/rCkQV/

If the others ones are dark, they can just inherit a class set for all LI's and the light overrides this.

```
$("ul li:nth-child(4n),ul li:nth-child(4n+1)").addClass("light");
```